# Trying to bind click, focus or blur event on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a bind event of either click, blur or focus on an input field that is created on the fly, this is the code I have inside my ajax call, but its not being called, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/JobClosing/Add",
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (data) {
      $(".heading").html(data.ID + " - " + data.Description);
      $("#ID").val(data.ID);
      MVCGrid.reloadGrid('NonFluentUsageExample');

      $(".datepicker").bind("focus", function() {
        console.log("Here");
        $(this).datepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: try unbind then bind

Comment: example please?

Comment: The code you have should work, although `bind()` was deprecated some time ago. Use `on()` instead. Are you sure the AJAX call is completing successfully?Check the console for errors.

Comment: @weber if the `bind()` didn't work what exactly are you expecting `ubind()` to fix?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, something like `$(".datepicker").unbind("focus").bind("focus", function(){})`

Comment: My point is, aside from outdated logic, if binding the event initially doesn't work unbinding it isn't going to do anything.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes the ajax call is completing successfully.

Comment: @user979331 do you see the `console.log("Here")`?

Comment: No, but if I put it out the bind call I see it.

Comment: What happens if you put this directly in the `success` function: `console.log($(".datepicker").length)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan checking

Comment: the console.log returns 0 :(

Comment: There's your problem, the element doesn't exist in the DOM in order to bind the event handler. We can't really help you with that given the code in the question, but at least you now know what to debug :)